# Combining zoom with maxwidth

Tags: imageresizer

I'm trying to do a image resizing operation where:

- Image stock is at 2x dimension (for Retina)
- If device detected is low resolution (standard), reduce image by 50% back to 1x (i.e. zoom=0.5)
- If device max resolution is 800, set the image not going over 800 (i.e. maxwidth=800)

However, when I combine the two operations (i.e. zoom=0.5&maxwidth=800), it basically give me an image that is 800 x 50% = 400. But I would like to have the image first reduced by 50% (e.g. if image was 2000w x 1000h, reduce it to 1000w x 500h), then make sure width does not go over 800 (i.e. 800w x 400h).

Is there any way to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

`Zoom` operates *after* all other sizing operations, such as width/height/maxwidth/maxheight. This ensures that you can add 'zoom' to any image command set and zoom the result.

I.e, **Zoom multiplies the 'result' size, not the source size.**

If you're doing responsive images, you should consider [trying slimmage.js](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage). It's rather ideal if you want to handle both pixel densities and CSS viewport or element rules effectively together.

If you really need to build your own solution, you'll need to do the math either client side (and set maxwidth alone) or server side (and add a command that applies your custom rules).

Full disclosure: I wrote [Slimmage](https://github.com/imazen/slimmage), so I personally think it's the best all-around solution, of course :)